# C# Xamarin.Forms How can I get Entry.text in ListView

Tags: c, xamarin.forms

I hope someone can help me.
First I'm sorry my English is not Good so I tried my best to describe my problem.

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" HasUnevenRows="True" HeightRequest="240" x:Name="Listview">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <Frame Padding="0" >
          <Grid Padding="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label x:Name="DistNumber" Text="{Binding DistNumber,StringFormat=' {0 :F0}'}" FontSize="18"   Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Entry  x:Name="Count" Placeholder="Choose Quantity" Text="{Binding Count,StringFormat=' {0 :F0}'}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                <Label x:Name="Quantity" Text="{Binding Quantity,StringFormat=' {0 :F0}'}" FontSize="18"   Grid.Column="3" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
              </Grid>
            </Frame>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
<Button Text="OK" Clicked="GoExport"></Button>
```

```
public partial class PopupB : PopupPage
    {
        ExportB evm;
        public PopupB()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            evm = new ExportB();
        }
        private async void GoExport(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }
```

ViewModels

```
class ExportB : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ExportB()
        {
            GetData();
        }

        public async void GetData()
        {
            //Get
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var ItemCode = Num.ItemCode;
                var WhsCode = Num.WhsCode;                
                var uri = "http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:8056/API/api/IO/GetBNumber?ItemCode=" + ItemCode + "&WhsCode=" + WhsCode;
                var result = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
                List<DataInventoryB> DataList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataInventoryB>>(result);
                Data = new ObservableCollection<DataInventoryB>(DataList);
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<DataInventoryB> _Data;
        public ObservableCollection<DataInventoryB> Data
        {
            get
            {
                return _Data;
            }
            set
            {
                _Data = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

```
public class DataInventoryB
    {
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }

        public string DistNumber{ get; set; }

        public string Quantity { get; set; }

        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
```

first the SQL Data will show on ListView that commodity quantity in warehouse,user can input the Quantity they want in Entry,finally user click Button.
I want get the Entry.Text that user input.

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your binded Item (e.g. `SomeItem`), and once you change the value of the fields in Model `SomeItem`, the item data in code-behind will also been changed accordingly.

You can refer to the following code:

```
public class SomeItem: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // public string DistNumber { get; set; }
    string _distNumber;
    public string DistNumber
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _distNumber, value); }

        get { return _distNumber; }
    }
    //public int Count { get; set; }
    int _count;
    public int Count
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _count, value); }
        get { return _count; }
    }
    //public int Quantity { get; set; }
    int _quantity;
    public int Quantity
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _quantity, value); }
        get { return _quantity; }
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

ListPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ListPage : ContentPage
{
    MyViewModel myViewModel;
    public ListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
        BindingContext = myViewModel;
    }

    private void GoExport_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (SomeItem item in myViewModel.items) {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("<----- item Name = " + item.Name + "<-----> item Count = " + item.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

ListPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:FormsListViewSample.ViewModels"
             x:Class="FormsListViewSample.Views.ListPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding items}" HasUnevenRows="True" HeightRequest="240" x:Name="Listview">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Frame Padding="0" >
                                <Grid Padding="0">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label x:Name="DistNumber" Text="{Binding DistNumber,StringFormat=' {0 :F0}'}" FontSize="18"   Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    <Entry  x:Name="Count" Placeholder="Choose Quantity" Text="{Binding Count,StringFormat=' {0 :F0}'}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                    <Label x:Name="Quantity" Text="{Binding Quantity,StringFormat=' {0 :F0}'}" FontSize="18"   Grid.Column="3" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Frame>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Button Text="OK" Clicked="GoExport_Clicked"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Note:**

According to your code ,in the entry, you binded field `Count`to the entry,so once changing the value in the entry, the `Count` in code-behind will also been changed.

```
<Entry  x:Name="Count" Placeholder="Choose Quantity" Text="{Binding Count,StringFormat=' {0 :F0}'}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
```

You can verify this in the button event:

```
       private void GoExport_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (SomeItem item in myViewModel.items) {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("<----- item Name = " + item.Name + "<-----> item Count = " + item.Count);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is my ViewModels. When the user enters the quantity into Entry.Text, the "Data" is still not updated. Could you please help me see it again? Thanks

Comment: Please make calss `DataInventoryB` implement interface  `INotifyPropertyChanged`  and make the corresponding field  `Count` like this:                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                     
    `int _count;
    public int Count
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _count, value); }
        get { return _count; }
    }`

Comment: please refer to  the class `SomeItem` in my answer.

Comment: Oh my God, it worked, sorry I am a newbie to C#, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have some options here, all have one thing in common: you have to add a field to your collection to store the user quantities.

First one is to bind the text to a field of the objects in `Data` collection:

```
<Entry  x:Name="Count" Placeholder="Choose Quantity" Text="{Binding UserQuantitiy}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />

// item class
class SomeItem
{
   public string DistNumber {get;set;}
   public int Quantity {get;set;}
   public int UserQuantity {get;set;} // this one is new
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to modify the original class, you can:

1. derive a new class with additional field and put those into the `Data` colelction:

```
class SomeItemWithUserQuantity : SomeItem 
{
   public int UserQuantity {get;set;} // bind entries to this
}
```

2. encapsulate the `SomeItem` class in another class and use that in the `DataCollection`:

```
class ItemWithUserQuantity
{
   public ItemWithUserQuantity(SomeItem item)
   {
       _item = item;
   }

   public int UserQuantity {get;set;} // bind to this
}
```

Encapsulation tends to be easier to handle on larger scale, plus you can make `ItemWithUserQuantity` generic to hold any type that users can choose the quantity.

Comment: Thank for your answer.I'am update my XAML and DataCollection. Now I want user click Button and Entry.Text will update in Data. How can I do now?